# Correct use of Callback for same operation and different type

Tags: c, struct, callback, void

I'm developing in C and I need ask an info about callback use.

Suppose I defined 3 callback with 3 different type in input for callback, example:

```
typedef void (*CB_1) (const struct paramType_1 *p);
typedef void (*CB_2) (const struct paramType_2 *p);
typedef void (*CB_3) (const struct paramType_3 *p);
```

Ok I have 3 array of callback, each for type of callback:

```
static CB_1         CB1List[10] ;
static CB_2         CB2List[10] ;
static CB_3         CB3List[10] ;
```

So I have defined 3 list of callback to call (in maybe different situation) and each list is of specific type of callback (CB_1 ,CB_2 or CB_3) that have a specific callback param (paramType_1,paramType_2 or paramType_3).

Suppose now that I need to perform an operation that is IDENTICAL for each callback ... I must copy paste 3 time the function due different specific param... suppose for example that i need to add a callback to array I need this;:

```
   static void CBAdd_1(CB_1 _cb) {   
      CB1List[i] = _cb
    }
   static void CBAdd_2(CB_2 _cb) {   
      CB2List[i] = _cb
    }
    static void CBAdd_3(CB_3 _cb) {  
      CB3List[i] = _cb
    }
```

what is a correct way to use a generic funcion "void CBAdd" for not replicate three time the function for the three callback? maybe using (void*) parameters or other?

thanks

Comment: I would probably use `void *` parameters I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a void* parameter like below. Alternatively (depends on your need) you might use a union instead of struct and store all the members in that single union type. Having that, a union type parameter will be passed to all functions and the function definition may decide which member to use.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct paramType_1
{
  int p;
} paramType_1;

typedef struct paramType_2
{
  int p;
} paramType_2;

typedef struct paramType_3
{
  int p;
} paramType_3;

typedef void (*CB) (const void* p);

static CB CBList[10];

void CB_1(const void* p)
{
  const paramType_1* pt = (paramType_1*)p;
  printf("p1: %d\n", pt->p);
}

void CB_2(const void* p)
{
  const paramType_2* pt = (paramType_2*)p;
  printf("p2: %d\n", pt->p);
}

void CB_3(const void *p)
{
  const paramType_3* pt = (paramType_3*)p;
  printf("p3: %d\n", pt->p);
}

static int c = 0;

static void CBAdd(CB cb_)
{
  CBList[c++] = cb_;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  paramType_1 p1;
  paramType_2 p2;
  paramType_3 p3;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    CBAdd(CB_1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    CBAdd(CB_2);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    CBAdd(CB_3);
  }

  p1.p = 1;
  p2.p = 2;
  p3.p = 3;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    (CBList[i])((void*)&p1);
  }

  for (i = 3; i < 6; i++)
  {
    (CBList[i])((void*)&p2);
  }

  for (i = 6; i < 9; i++)
  {
    (CBList[i])((void*)&p3);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Goodmorning! Thanks for your answer! Now I test it!